# Hausdorff convergence of preimages of discrete-valued functions

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, limits-and-convergence, metric-spaces

Suppose $f_n$, $f:X\to K$ where $K$ is a finite set and $(X,d)$ is a metric space. Suppose also that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ for all $x\in X$ (pointwise convergence). Finally, let $d_H$ be the [Hausdorff metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance) on subsets of $X$.

Do these conditions guarantee Hausdorff convergence of the preimages $f_n^{-1}(y)=\{x\in X : f_n(x)=y\}$, i.e. is it true that 
$$d_H(f_n^{-1}(y), f^{-1}(y))\to 0\text{ for each }y\in K?$$

Comment: I guess the answer is yes, if $X$ is compact, otherwise in general no.

Comment: @PietroMajer Do you have a proof / sketch of proof? Or a counterexample when $X$ is noncompact.

Comment: counterexamples are easy, and the guess was hurried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rephrase your question in the following way. Let $A_n=f_n^{-1}(y)$ and $A=f^{-1}(y)$, which are a generic sets basically. Your only relation between these sets is that $A=\liminf A_n$ and $X\backslash A=\liminf (X\backslash A_n)$, i.e. $A=\lim A_n$. Then your question becomes:

> Is it correct that if in a metric space $A=\lim A_n$ (as sets), then $A$ is the Hausdorff limit of $A_n$?

The answer to this question is "no".

For a counterexample take $A_n=[n,+\infty)$ or $A_n=[n,n+1]$ and $A=\varnothing$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

The answer is still "no" even in the case when $A$ and every $A_n$ are non-empty and closed, and $X$ is compact. Consider $X=[-1,1]$, $A=[-1,0]$ and $A_{n}=[-1,0]\cup\{a_n\}$, where $\{a_{n},n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is an arbitrary enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}\cap (0,1]$. Then it is easy to check that $A=\lim A_n$, but $d_H(A_n,A)\not\to 0$ as long as $a_n\not\to0$.

(It is worth pointing out that Hausdorff distance mostly makes sense when the sets are closed and bounded. As the examples above illustrate, even under this additional assumption the question is false.)

Comment: Your argument seems fairly intuitive, but I am not certain what you mean by $\lim A_n$, or the sequence $a_n$ you have constructed...

Comment: @JohnA By definition $\limsup A_n=\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}\cup_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m$ and $\liminf A_n=\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\cap_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m$. These sets consist of elements which are contained in the infinite number of $A_n$ /all but finite number of $A_n$. If $\limsup A_n=\liminf A_n$ we say that this set is $\lim A_n$.

Comment: The sequence $a_n$ is just an arbitrary numeration of the rational numbers of $(0,1]$.